# Feeds import creating more nodes instead of replacing or updating - Drupal 7

Tags: 7, nodes

I have Feeds module, but even if I use the correct "guid" and it appears in feeds_item database table, and I configured it to "Update" (also tried "Replace") existing nodes, and "Delete" non-existing nodes, it will create more nodes, so my database is getting higher and higher Nid numbers. I am using Feeds Tamper submodule. What can be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem: I had not set "Guid" as unique identifier, that is the reason it was duplicating the rows in the database and why it was not replacing or updating the content. The problem now is how to reset the node->nid number to a reasonable number after all these deleted entries.